# Apply chosen download location as default

Tags: android

I let the user choose his own download location but once chosen, the file still gets downloaded to constant value "HOME".
I think this value needs to be replaced with the chosen download location from user but i have no idea how.

Thank you for helping me.

```
//choose download location//
public void onClick(final View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.pick_location_dialog_ok: {
            if (listener != null) {
                final EditText path = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pick_location_dialog_path);
                final String loc = path.getText().toString();
                listener.onDownloadLocationChanged(loc);
            }
            dismiss();
        }
            break;
        case R.id.pick_location_dialog_cancel: {
            dismiss();
        }
            break;
        case R.id.pick_location_dialog_choose_path: {

            //
        }
            break;
    }
}

//applies onDownloadLocationChanged//
public void onDownloadLocationChanged(final String newLocation) {
    final Settings settings = new Settings(this);
    final String original = settings.getDownloadsLocation();
    if (!newLocation.equals(original)) {
        new File(newLocation).mkdirs();
        settings.setDownloadsLocation(newLocation);

        final SettingsMenuItem item = (SettingsMenuItem) findViewById(R.id.settings_download_location);
        item.setValue(newLocation);

        final AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        b.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        b.setMessage(R.string.settings_auto_check_updates);
        b.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                new MoveFilesTask(SettingsActivity.this, original, newLocation).execute();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        b.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        b.create().show();
    }
}

    }
    //
    //
    //excutes download with choosen path, replace Constants.HOME with chosen download location//
    final File parentDir = new File(Constants.HOME, title);
    if (!parentDir.exists())
        parentDir.mkdirs();
      final File file = new File(parentDir, (filename));
    notification = new ProgressNotification(DownloaderService.this, file);
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    new Thread() 
    {

public class Constants {
//
public static final File HOME = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        "homeloc");
//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself, here is the correct code:

```
@Override
public void onStart(final Intent intent, final int startId) {

//
    final Settings settings = new Settings(this);
    final File parentDir = new File(settings.getDownloadsLocation() + "/", title);
//

}
```